# Convert matrix's coordinate to respective array's coordinate

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, coordinates

I want to convert matrix's (n, m) coordinates as i, j to respective array's (n * m) coordinates as k, thus matrix[i, j] will be equivalents to array[k]. I don't know how to create an expression that makes this conversion.

### I want to find who is k

Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a 2D array index into a 1D index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730961/convert-a-2d-array-index-into-a-1d-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds suspiciously like homework.

Assuming the matrix size is known already as n and m... Here's an algorithm in JavaScript:

```
var a = new Array(  );
for( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for( j = 0; j < m; j++) {
         a[ (i * m) + j ] = matrix[ i ][ j ];
    }
}
```

EDIT: fixed the index expression for a[]

Comment: I see you say you fixed the index expression - sure that's not a[i*m+j] - I think you want (1,m-1) just before (2,0)?