# Translate a 2D coordinate into a 1D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

I have also read:

[Convert a 2D array index into a 1D index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730961/convert-a-2d-array-index-into-a-1d-index)

I am trying to debug my program and I would need to understand how could we convert a 2d coordinate into a 1d coordinate.

If I have an IJ coordinate, for example: (3284,1352) and we want to access an unidimensional array which is (3492,2188), how could we achieve that?

Until now I have tried:

1) I thought that you offset for each row and inside each row for each column as:

```
i x j = 3284 * 1352 = 4.439.968
```

If we have that the coordinate (3284,1352) graphically corresponds to the segment which has a gray level intensity of 1:

[image]

And we try to access the unidimensional array which has for each pixel its gray value, in pixel: `4.439.968` we have:

[image]

A gray intensity of `14`

Which is quite strange because of:

-> Segment number 14 is not being displayed by ITKSnap:

[image]

-> Our segment has a gray level of 1, so then we should after manually calculating which index to access, find that gray level:

[image]

2) The second way I have tried is to calculate it as:

```
column clicked * number of total rows + row clicked;

j * xLength + i;
```

In our example is:

```
1352 * 3492 + 3284 = 4.724.468
```

If we try to find that pixel in the data:

[image]

We find that the gray level is 0, which corresponds to the background.

What is wrong with the conversion?

Could you help me please?

Comment: I think it should be: `row clicked * number of total columns + column clicked;` as it usually goes through columns then rows (it goes left to right then top to bottom).

Answer (score 4):

I think you need something like this: `index = (y * maxColumns) + x`
(looks like your j=x and i=y)

I drew something to visualize it:
[image: 2d to 1d array]

Comment: I don't think that `Math.round` call is necessary. It all just integer arithmitics, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right I just copied it out from a project where I was calculating the total columns with `Math.sqrt`. (And I recently had problems with trying to access an array with a float value, because there is no int in JS, so I now put a `Math.round` everywhere ;D )